# Friend function used for output stream operator shown error as not accessible

Tags: c++, friend

I have written simple class like below in file VRKVector.h

```
namespace vrk {
class VRKVector {

private:
    std::vector<int> m_coordinates;
    int              m_dimension;
    
public:
    /** VRKVector constructor.
      * @param coordinates which represents a vector coordinates.
      * @return none.
    */
    VRKVector(std::vector<int> coordinates);

    /** operator << : output stream operator
      * @param out which is output stream we want to write
      * @param vector which represents a vector coordinates.
      * @return none.
    */
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector);

    };
}

VRKVector.cpp

// ============================================================================
// Local includes, e.g. files in the same folder, typically corresponding declarations.
#include "VRKVector.h"


// ============================================================================
// System includes, e.g. STL.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>




// namespace declarations;
using namespace std;
using namespace vrk;

VRKVector::VRKVector(std::vector<int> coordinates) {
    m_coordinates = coordinates;
    m_dimension = coordinates.size();
}


std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector) {
    out << vrkvector.m_dimension;
    return out; // return std::ostream so we can chain calls to operator<<
}
```

Above code I am getting error as shown below

```
1>C:\VRKVector.cpp(42,18): error C2248: 'vrk::VRKVector::m_dimension': cannot access private member declared in class 'vrk::VRKVector'
1>C:\\VRKVector.h(40): message : see declaration of 'vrk::VRKVector::m_dimension'
```

We can assess private member as we have friend function. Why am I seeing the error?

Comment: wrong namespace. You friended `std::ostream& vrk::operator << (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector);` and defined  `std::ostream& ::operator << (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector);` (global scope).

Comment: Here is fixed [mcve] https://godbolt.org/z/neTnEs

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `operator<<` in the namespace `vrk`, the [`friend` declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declares it as the member of the namespace `vrk`.

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, ...

```
std::ostream& vrk::operator<< (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector) {
//            ^^^^^
    out << vrkvector.m_dimension;
    return out; // return std::ostream so we can chain calls to operator<<
}
```

Comment: @venkysmarty You should accept it if the answer helped you solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector){}
```

Is not the definition of

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, vrk::VRKVector &vrkvector);
```

As it's in a different namespace, it can't access the private class member as is to be expected, a global function can't access a given class private members.

You can fix it by using one of the following options:

- Defining it inline:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, vrk::VRKVector &vrkvector){
    out << vrkvector.m_dimension;
    return out; // return std::ostream so we can chain calls to operator<<
}
```

- Defining it inside the namespace.
- Using namespace scope:

```
std::ostream& vrk::operator<< (std::ostream& out, vrk::VRKVector& vrkvector) { 
    /*...*/
}
```